# Django REST XMLParser() - cannot parse item list

Tags: python, django, xml-parsing, django-rest-framework

I am trying to parse a list of items using Django REST XMLParser. The parser is treating the list of items, as s single item. Here is the XML:

```
XML = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <root>
                <item>
                    <ID>item_1</ID>
                    <Description>first item</Description>
                </item>
                <item>
                    <ID>item_2</ID>
                    <Description>second item</Description>
                </item>
                </root>
            """
```

And here is the parser:

```
from django.conf import settings    
settings.configure()
from django.utils.six import BytesIO
from rest_framework_xml.parsers import XMLParser

data_stream = BytesIO(XML)
parsed_data = XMLParser().parse(data_stream)

print parsed_data
```

This returns the following json:

```
{'item': {'ID': 'item_2', 'Description': 'second item'}}
```

So it appears XMLParser() is writing over list item 1, and returning list item 2. From the code above, I would expect:

```
[{'item': {'ID': 'item_1', 'Description': 'first item'}}, {'item': {'ID': 'item_2', 'Description': 'second item'}}]
```

Comment: maybe a bug: https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-xml/issues/11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the source, I think you need to change `<item>` to `<list-item>`. The tag name seems to be hard coded:

https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-xml/blob/master/rest_framework_xml/parsers.py#L51

UPDATE in response to your comment:

This xml parsing/rendering done by the DRF is part of serialization. It is probably not meant as an OXM (Object-XML Mapping). Have a look at https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-xml/blob/master/rest_framework_xml/renderers.py#L21 - you should use the renderer to create the xml that you later parse with the parser.

Caveat: I haven't used the XML part of DRF, I'm just reading its code.

Comment: if true, that's a massive assumption on behalf of django-rest-framework-xml for my application (parsing b2mml XML) the 'item' tag is <MaterialSubLot></MaterialSubLot> and there are many other applications that won't use a tag called "list-item".